# Convert a Bitstring into an integer value

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, string

I have got a String filled up with 0 and 1 and would like to get an Integer out of it:

```
String bitString = ""; 
int Number;
int tmp;

bitString = "";
  for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
    tmp= analogRead (A0);
    bitString +=  tmp % 2;
    delay(50);
  }
// now bitString contains for example "10100110" 
// Number = bitstring to int <-------------
// In the end I want that the variable Number contains the integer 166
```

Comment: What is the question? What do you expect this code to do and what is it doing? What else have you tried?

Comment: @Craig I eddited the question. For example If the bitString contains a "10100110" I want the programm to save it as the decimal 166 in the int variable.

Comment: Do you need the string? You could create the integer representation directly.

Comment: @Craig i would also like to print out the bitstring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need the string for printing you can store value in an integer and then use the [Serial.print(number,BIN)](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) function to format the output as a binary value.  Appending integers to strings is a potentially costly operation both in performance and memory usage.

```
int Number = 0;
int tmp;

for (int i=9;i>=0;i--) {
  tmp = analogRead (A0);
  Number += (tmp % 2) << i;
  delay(50);
}
Serial.print(Number, BIN);
```

Comment: Yes your solution looks more efficient! and does the work

Answer (score 5):

Check out `strtoul()`

It should work something like this:

`unsigned long result = strtoul(bitstring.c_str(), NULL, 2);`

Now you have a long variable which can be converted into an int if needed.

Comment: @kimliv Did you add .c_str() to the end of bitstring as Peter pointed out above? c_str() should return a const char*.

Comment: it is working that way!